# How to disable system's bold text accessibility setting in iOS for React Native apps?

Tags: ios, react-native

After turning on the Bold Text setting, RN Texts are all forced to be bold.

Putting allowFontScaling={false} to Text elements works for overriding iOS's font scaling setting, but is there any way for overriding the bold text setting as well? Thanks

Comment: did u find a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find a way to do this?